# Create a calendar event with popup dialogs using applescript

Tags: calendar, applescript

I need some help since I am new to this, appreciate any inputs. I am trying to setup a script to create a calendar event, asking me date, time and duration of the event, but I am messing up something since it keeps giving me errors such as Can’t make "19.12.1820:06:17" into type number, I guess they are related to formatting or something else?

```
tell application "Calendar"
activate
tell calendar "Work"
    set theCurrentDate to short date string of (current date)
    set theCurrentTime to time string of (current date)
    --Get event Summary
    display dialog "Enter event name:" default answer "Appointment"
    set eventName to text returned of the result
    --Get date
    display dialog "Please enter a date for your event" default answer theCurrentDate
    set eventDate to text returned of the result
    --Get time
    display dialog "Please enter start time" default answer theCurrentTime
    set eventTime to text returned of the result
    set eventStart to eventDate & eventTime
    --Get duration 
    display dialog "Please enter duration in minutes" default answer "120"
    set eventDuration to text returned of the result
    set eventEnd to eventStart + (eventDuration * minutes)
    make new event at end with properties {summary:eventName, location:"url Intercall: xxx PIN: xxx", start date:eventStart, end date:eventEnd, url:"url"}
end tell
reload calendars
end tell
```

Comment: You need to also include what errors you're getting. Have a look at: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: eventDate in your script is not a date but a text. You must coerce is to a date : set myDate to date (eventDate). Also eventDuration is not a number, but a text. You must coerce is to an integer : Set myMinutes to eventDuration as integer

Comment: @pbell There's no need to coerce a string representation of a number to an integer, as AppleScript does this automatically when performing calculations.  Boa, in order to get user input and utilise it as a `date` object in AppleScript, you're best obtaining the components (day, month year) and mapping them onto an AppleScript `date` object.  See [my answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/345704/266364) for a solution to a very similar problem.